# Unifying Mathematical Framework for Probability Distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The twelvefold way (and as an extension, the twentyfold way) describes counting problems in terms of a single mathematical framework, functions with certain features mapping domains with certain features to codomains with certain features.  This eliminates the need to anchor each formula to its own specialized physical scenario, instead letting them all be described as an n-fold Cartesian product of a small number of features.

Does something similar exist for probability distributions?  Instead of thinking of the Poisson distribution as the probability of a given number of events occurring in a fixed interval of time, the Binomial distribution as the number of successes in a sequence of experiments, etc., is there a way to sort them into a more organized mathematical framework, such as the n-fold Cartesian product of a few features?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking for but this might be relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family

Answer (score 2):

I am curious what the twelvefold and twentyfold way are, but I would say that probability distributions are all examples of the mathematical object known as a "measure," and more specifically as examples of "probability measures on $\mathbb R$." Not to get too bogged down in the details, if $\mathcal B$ is a collection of subsets of the real numbers, then we say "$P$ is a probability measure on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B)$" if $P$ is a function $\mathcal B\to [0,1]$ that satisfies a few properties:

1. $P(E) \ge 0$ for every $E\in \mathcal B$,
2. $P(\mathbb R) = 1$,
3. $P(\bigsqcup_j E_j) = \sum_j P(E_j)$ whenever $\{E_j\}\subset \mathcal B$.

The collection of subsets $\mathcal B$ that is most commonly considered in probability theory is the collection of [Borel sets.](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Borel_set)

In this framework, the Poisson distribution of rate $\lambda$ is a measure $\mathrm{Pois}_\lambda\colon\mathcal B\to[0,1]$ that satisfies
$$
\mathrm{Pois}_\lambda(\{k\}) = e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}, \qquad k = 0,1,2,\dots,
$$
and $\mathrm{Pois}_\lambda(E) = 0$ for all $E\in\mathcal B$ such that $E\cap\{0,1,2,\dots\} = \emptyset$. Similarly, the binomial distribution of parameters $n$ and $p$ is a measure $\mathrm{Bin}(n,p)\colon\mathcal B\to [0,1]$ that satisfies
$$
\mathrm{Bin}(n,p)(\{k\}) = {n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}, \qquad k\in\{0,1,\dots,n\},
$$
and $\mathrm{Bin}(n,p)(E) = 0$ for all $E$ such that $E\cap\{0,1,\dots,n\} = \emptyset$.